# When using recursion, how can I append or concatenate multiple pairs into a single, longer list?

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

This is a homework problem, so please point in a good direction w/o giving a solution.
Basically, within Scheme, I am trying to build a multi-bit adder starting with logic gates.

Thanks for reading/helping.

An example I am running is adding 101001 and 011101 with a 1 carry in.
I feel like I had a list and be appending throughout? But if this is the correct step, I cannot get this to work.

```
(define l-and (lambda (x y) (if (and (equal? x 1) (equal? y 1)) 1 0)))

(define l-or (lambda (x y) (if (or (equal? x 1) (equal? y 1)) 1 0)))

(define l-xor (lambda (x y) (if (or (equal? (l-and x y) 1) (and (equal? x 0) (equal? y 0)) ) 0 1)))

(define l-not (lambda (x) (if (equal? x 0) 1 0)))

(define fulladdr (lambda (x y z)
  (cons
  (l-xor (l-xor x y) z)
  (l-or (l-and x y) (l-and z (l-xor x y)))
  )
))

(define (removelast lis)
  ;(display (reverse(cdr (reverse lis)))) For debugging
  (if (null? (cdr lis)) 
  '() 
  (reverse(cdr (reverse lis)
))))

(define (last-element lis)
  ;(display (car(reverse lis))) For debugging
  (if (null? (cdr lis)) 
  '() (car(reverse lis))
))

(define n-bit-addr (lambda (l1 l2 x) 
  (if (or (null? l1) (null? l2)) 
  '() 
  (let ((carry (cdr (fulladdr (last-element l1) (last-element l2) x)))) 
  (let (( sum (car (fulladdr (last-element l1) (last-element l2) x))))
  ;(display carry) For debugging
  (cons
    (fulladdr (last-element l1) (last-element l2) x)
      (n-bit-addr (removelast l1) (removelast l2) carry)

)))))
```

When I run my code with this example, a couple others, I get the correct output, kind of: ((1 . 1) (1 . 0) (1 . 0) (0 . 1) (0 . 1) (0 . 1))
I am trying to figure out how to format this so my output would be (111000.1).  Basically (Binary . FinalCarry)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations. An adder uses carry so you'll need to operate on leas significant digits to most significant.

A list is created from end to beginning. eg. `(1 2)` can be created `(cons 1 (cons 2 '()))` which means the second argument `(cons 2 '())` needs to be finished.

I guess your arguments are binary digits in a list like `(1 0 1 0)` as `10`. If you had a helper or a named `let` you could have the two arguments so far, the carry and sum as parameters so that you can use them as state. Also you are calling `fulladdr` with the same arguments 3 times. Here is what I think you should do:

```
(define (n-bit-addr l1 l2)
  (helper (reverse l1) (reverse l2) 0 '()))
```

This defeats the purpose of getting and removing the "last" element and rather fetching and removing the first, which is much easier to do in Scheme.

Now here is the rest. I've abstracted some of the challenged out eg. what happens when you do `(n-bit-addr '(1 1) '(1 1 1 0))` is magically worked around by not using `car` and `cdr` directly.

```
(define (helper l1 l2 carry acc)
  ;; actual implementation of n-bit-addr
  (if (finished? l1 l2)
      (finish acc carry)
      (let* ((res (fulladdr (car0 l1) (car0 l2) carry))
             (sum (car res))
             (carry (cdr res)))
        (helper (cdr* l1) <??> <??> <??>))))

(define (car0 lst)
  ;; returns 0 if lst is null? (car lst) otherwise
  )

(define (cdr* lst)
  ;; return '() if lst is null? (cdr lst) otherwise
  )

(define (finished? l1 l2)
  ;; return #t is both are null?
  )

(define (finish sum carry)
  ;; return whatever structure one would want with the last result
  ;; I would imagine carry could be the the highest bit if it's set. thus
  ;; (n-bit-addr '(1) '(1)) ; ==> (1 0)
  )
```

Now if `(1 0 1 0)` is not satisfactory you should make `number->logic` and `logic->number` that transform `(1 0 1 0)` to `#b1010`. This can easily be done with list iteration and arithmetic. Since you want to know how to do lists to number I'll do the other way:

```
(define (number->logic n)
  (let loop ((n n) (acc '()))
    (cond ((not (zero? n)) (loop (quotient n 2) (cons (remainder n 2) acc)))
          ((null? acc) '(0))
          (else acc))))

(number->logic #b1010) ; ==> (1 0 1 0)
```

Note that `#b1010` is just a fancy way of writing `10`

```
(number->logic 10) ; ==> (1 0 1 0)
```

The other way around would be to start the accumulator at 0 and for each element in the list in order multiply the accumulator with 2 and add the bit. When the list is `null?` the accumulator would be the number.

```
(logic->number '(1 0 1 0)) ; ==> 10
```

I remember building adders with nand gates at School, but I haven't done so in programming. You should try it.